# Exception Tomcat with Spring Security

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, apache-tomee

When I try to add to my pom.xml these dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and then I start Tomcat, this error occurs:

```
Grave: Error listenerStart
lug 31, 2014 10:57:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Context [/MyApp] startup failed due to previous errors
lug 31, 2014 10:57:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Informazioni: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
lug 31, 2014 10:57:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
Grave: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What's wrong? I don't have jar under WEB-INF\lib, but they are all under maven folder and I already use 3.2.2.RELEASE for spring-core/web/contetext. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try cleaning your server before restarting it.

Comment: Already done. But the exception be left.

Comment: And that's the only exception? There is nothing further up the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] In my spring-security.xml, the version was wrong:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

instead it must be:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
```

Thanks anyway @Ben Green.